# while cin.get leading to an infinite loop when loading from file

Tags: c++, unix, c++11, cin

I have the following code (this just part of a bigger application but the issue seems to be coming from the following):

```
char inputChar;
while (cin.get(inputChar)){
    cout<< inputChar<< "\n";
}
```

when providing the application with its input from the console, such as:
'echo "aaaaa aaaaa"|tst' (where the program above has been compiled to tst.out) the program works correctly, however when I provide the input via a text file (ie './tst mytest.txt') it seems to run into an infinite loop (the cursor just moves to the next line and remains there, never getting the prompt again) no matter the contents of the file itself.

Does anyone have any idea as to why this is happening, and what i can do to fix this behavior.

ps: I am compiling and running this on a unix terminal.

Thanks

Comment: Interactive IO waits for a user input, a pipe has an EOF. Let the user enter Ctrl-D for EOF

Comment: Are you sure you're describing the cases correctly? `echo "aaaa aaaaa" | tst` would read from the pipe, `./tst mytest.txt` would normally use interactive input.

Comment: To read from a file you need to create an ifstream object.  cin reads from the standard input.

Comment: I can't use an ifstream object as the application itself must remain generic as the input may be provided via a file or console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to handle both file and cin input:

```
std::ifstream myFile;

if (argc > 1) 
{
    myFile.open(argv[1]);
}

if (myFile.is_open()) 
{
    readMyInput(myFile);
    myFile.close();
} else 
{
    readMyInput(std::cin);
}

void readMyInput(std::istream &inputStream)
{
    char myCharacter;
    while (inputStream.get(myCharacter)) 
    {
        cout<< myCharacter<< "\n";
    }
}
```

if you don't want to open a file: `cat input.txt | ./tst.out` will feed `std::cin` input stream

Comment: If i were to use get line then the resulting output would be different then the one above, as the above would return a character per line while this would result in a line per line.

Comment: Is there a way to pass the contents of a file to the application without having the application read the file itself?

Comment: cat input.txt | ./tst.out    will feed std::cin input stream

Comment: This seems to work...ill use this instead of ./tst mytest.txt. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not a paticularly good method, and there is probably a better way, but you could try this:

```
if(cin.get() == "SOME_CHARACTER_CHANGE_THIS") {
    cout << "SOME_CHARACTER_CHANGE_THIS_ALSO" << endl;
}
```

For each character that can be typed in.

Comment: I need the program to be able to read whatever input it is provided, so i cannot do the above for all possible characters.

Comment: Sorry. I was starting to think that myself. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

The code in your example isn't reading from the file, it's reading from stdin.  If you want to read from a file, you'll have to initialize an `ifstream` with the filename passed into `main` and read from that instead of `cin`.

Comment: My apologies for the inaccurate description. What I want to do is to be able to run the application by doing ''./tst mytest.txt'' without it going into an infinite loop. (I was under the impression that this meant that the contents of the file are read and given to the application as its input.)